# SQL Server GUID to VarChar(36) or Char(36)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, char, guid, varchar

I am replacing some GUID column types, since I need to do some `Group By` work in MSSQL 2008. I was about to change the types to Char(36) since I know the exact size of the value, but after Googling a bit I see lots of people doing Varchar(36) instead. Isn't it better to do CHAR in this case?

Comment: Just interested. Why do you need to use `varchar/char` instead of `uniqueidentifier` in group by?

Comment: Doing aggregation on very large sets of URL data and the URLs are aliased by GUIDs, need to do some group by and summing and that can't be done with Uniqueidentifier AFAIK.

Comment: The simple tests I have done showed no problems. I found http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Types/uniqueidentifierusageandlimitations/1406/ . A rather old article so perhaps is was the case in SQL Server 2000. I have tested in SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between CHAR and VARCHAR is how space is allocated. CHAR fields are always the size defined, but until a VARCHAR field actually has data in it, then it will occupy 0 bytes.

In your case though, because you're always going to be storing 36 characters, I would suggest you keep using CHAR. If you were storing data of varying length, go with VARCHAR.

However, are you really trying to use a GROUP BY on a GUID? They are called "Globally Unique Identifier" for a reason. Or are you splitting them up, and grouping by certain sections of the GUID (which can be the same, but overall, generally, none are the same).

Comment: Group by on guid makes sense if summing etc. multiple records relating to that guid.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer: Use CHAR(36) or better yet BINARY(16).

The long answer: You would probably be better off leaving the column types alone and using CAST in your queries.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (x UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, y INT)
-- Insert some data here
SELECT
    MIN(y),
    CAST(a.x AS BINARY(16))
FROM
    @a AS a
GROUP BY
    CAST(a.x AS BINARY(16))
```